# How to match two different Object ids using MongoDB find() query?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have an entry like below,

```
[
  {
    "_id":ObjectId("59ce020caa87df4da0ee2c78"),
    "name": "Tom",
    "owner_id": ObjectId("59ce020caa87df4da0ee2c78")
  },
  {
    "_id":ObjectId("59ce020caa87df4da0ee2c79"),
    "name": "John",
    "owner_id": ObjectId("59ce020caa87df4da0ee2c78")
  }
]
```

now, I need to find the person whose `_id` is equal to `owner_id` using find() in MongoDB.
Note, we can't not use $match (aggregation) due to some reason.

I am using this query,

```
db.people.find({ $where:  "this._id == this.owner_id" })
```

but, it's not returning the expected output. Can anyone help me with this.

Thanks.

Comment: Try with the `$expr` with aggregate `$eq` operator (instead of `$where`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `$expr` and `$eq` you can get desired values avoiding the use of `$where` into a find stage (not aggregation necessary).

```
db.collection.find({
  "$expr": {
    "$eq": [
      "$_id",
      "$owner_id"
    ]
  }
})
```

Comment: For added context we try not to use { where: '' } because it executes that as JS and it'll be much slower.

Comment: Hi, @J.F., is there any way to do it without using $expr?